# I don't understand the difference between a char array and a char * string

Tags: c

I made the following little program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void strncpy(char * s, char * t, int n);

int
main()
{
    char string1[]="Learning strings";
    char string2[10];
    strncpy(string2,string1,3);
    printf("string1:%s\nstring2:%s\n",string1,string2);
    return 0;
}

void strncpy(char * s, char * t, int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<n && t[i]!=0;i++)
        s[i]=t[i];
    s[i]=0;
}
```

I was trying to learn the difference between doing something like:

```
char greeting[]="Hello!";
```

And

```
char * farewell="Goodbye!";
```

And I thought my program would work with either of the two types of 'strings'(correct way of saying it?), but it only works with the first one.

Why does this happen? What's the difference between the two types?

What would I have to do to my program to be able to use strings of the second type?

Comment: have a look here http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/#arrays

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c

**Someone should mark this as duplicate.**

Comment: I added another question that's not answered in that post, thanks for the references!

Comment: Read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement

```
char greeting[] = "Hello!";
```

causes the compiler to work out the size of the string literal `"Hello!"` (7 characters including the terminating `'\0'`), create an array of that size, and then copy that string into that array.   The result of that `greeting` can be modified (e.g. its characters overwritten).

The statement

```
char * farewell="Goodbye!";
```

creates a pointer that points at the first character in the string literal `"Goodbye!"`.   That string literal cannot be modified without invoking undefined behaviour.

Either `greeting` or `farewell` can be passed to any function that does not attempt to modify them.   `greeting` can also be passed to any function which modifies it (as long as only characters `greeting[0]` through to `greeting[6]` are modified, and no others).   If `farewell` is modified, the result is undefined behaviour.

Generally speaking, it is better to change the definition  of `farewell` to

```
const char * farewell="Goodbye!";
```

which actually reflects its true nature (and will, for example, cause a compilation error if `farewell` is passed to a function expecting a non-`const` parameter).    The fact that it is possible to define `farewell` as a non-`const` pointer while it points at (the first character of) a string literal is a historical anomaly.

And, of course, if you want `farewell` to be safely modifiable, declare it as an array, not as a pointer.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks!! I understand it now. One more question, if it's not too much of a bother: Why would you use char pointers like this if they have no advantages over char arrays?

Comment: I did not suggest there are no advantages of pointers over arrays.   It is possible to create a modifiable array of `const` pointers.   It is significantly more difficult to achieve a comparable result without pointers.

Answer (score 1):

The string literals `"Hello"` and `"Goodbye"` are stored as arrays of `char` such that they are allocated at program startup and released at program exit, and are visible over the entire program.  They may be stored in such a way that they cannot be modified (such as in a read-only data segment).  Attempting to modify the contents of a string literal results in *undefined behavior*, meaning the compiler isn't required to handle the situation in any particular way - it may work the way you want, it may result in a segmentation violation, or it may do so ething else.

The line

```
char greeting[] = "Hello";
```

allocates enough space to hold a copy of the literal and writes the contents of the literal to it.  You may modify the contents of this array at will (although you can't store strings longer than `"Hello"` to it).

The line

```
char *farewell = "Goodbye";
```

creates a pointer and writes the address of the string literal `"Goodbye"` to it.  Since this is a pointer to a string literal, we cannot write to the contents of the literal through that pointer.